# Iterating over date column with period column until end date; grouping results by id column.

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime

I know similar questions have been asked on this website, but the other solutions I've seen don't really address my problem.

I have this data:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'CustomerID': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
           'Date': np.random.choice(pd.Series(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', 
            freq='D', periods=180)), 6),
           'Credits': np.random.uniform(0,1000,6),
           'Credit Days': np.random.uniform(0, 1000, 6),
          }, columns=['Date', 'CustomerID', 'Credits', 'Credit Days'])
sample
```

For each company, I want to essentially add `'Date' + 'Credit Days'`, and from that resulting date, add `'Credit Days'` again, until the end date goes over 2020-01-01. I also want to group each date by CustomerID in a new dataframe.

thanks.

Comment: How do the repeated additions relate to the grouping by customer? When you group the dates by customer, what do you want to do with them? (i.e. store them in a list nested inside the DataFrame, take the average/max/min/count)

Comment: The dates from repeated additions are projections for purchases. I later want to group each purchase date in a month/quarter/year by company, so that's why I need those specific parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do division but you're thinking about it in terms of repeated addition.

```
doomsday = pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01')
time_left = doomsday - sample.Date
ratio = time_left.dt.days / sample['Credit Days']
```

That gives you:

```
0     0.628771
1     4.563582
2     5.528058
3     0.942857
4     1.071486
5    20.097542
```

You can round that up or down as needed, and multiply it back if you like:

```
sample.Date + pd.to_timedelta(sample['Credit Days'], 'd') * ratio.round()
```

Which gives you:

```
0   2020-12-22 00:20:19.857580800
1   2020-03-09 11:19:03.895536000
2   2020-02-23 10:37:54.541632000
3   2020-02-06 01:26:56.634835200
4   2019-11-18 21:37:24.674937600
5   2019-12-28 13:03:52.781760000
```

As for groupby, that's a separate question, and one I'm confident you can work out by checking other questions already asked about that specifically.

Comment: The problem is, I need every exact iterated date for each CustomerId. That's why I need to group the result by the customerid, and not just make a new column for the ratios.

Comment: @Chad: Oh.  Well, I showed you how to find out how many dates there are for each customer--try using `np.arange()` for each customer from the start date to the end date.